# how to get user context / thread id to distinguish between task sequences

Tags: locust

I have a task sequence to execute multiple times, with multiple different users.  Is there something  I can write into the log file to identify an action being taken by  user1 vs user2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to add in my output to a custom CSV file the login id for the user, and an iteration counter.  This way I can uniquely distinguish between task sequences because they are identified by email address and the counter.

This works for non-distributed testing.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on exactly what you're trying to do, but the easiest way is probably to just name your request differently, using the `name=` parameter. (assuming you dont have lots of users)

e.g

```
self.client.post("/login", data={ "username": username }, name=f"/login {username}")
```

Comment: What we would like to do is track response times by task sequence and save  that in a CSV file. Sometimes we see a spike in response time in the middle of the  load test and  we would like to capture more detail at the task sequence level.

Comment: When you say ”track by sequence” do you mean to differentiate requests between different TaskSequences? Or between iterations of the same task? Either way, try naming your requests uniquely (you’ll need to keep track of your iteration count yourself, if that is what you are after)

Comment: yes - differentiate between task sequences.  i think i figured out a solution.